# Test whether a UIView is in the middle of animation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-animation, uiviewanimation

Is there any way to tell if a UIView is in the middle of an animation?  When I print out the view object while it is moving I notice that there is an "animations" entry:

```
search bar should end editing: <UISearchBar: 0x2e6240; frame = (0 0; 320 88); text = ''; autoresize = W+BM; animations = { position=<CABasicAnimation: 0x6a69c40>; bounds=<CABasicAnimation: 0x6a6d4d0>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x2e6e00>>
```

When the animation has stopped and I print the view, the "animations" entry is now gone:

```
search bar should end editing: <UISearchBar: 0x2e6240; frame = (0 0; 320 88); text = ''; autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x2e6e00>>
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A `UIView` has a layer ([`CALayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)). You can send [`animationKeys`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW102) to it, which will give you an array of keys which identify the animations attached to the layer. I suppose that if there are any entries, the animation(s) are running. If you want to dig even deeper have a look at the [`CAMediaTiming` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html) which `CALayer` adopts. It does some more information on the current animation.

**Important**: If you add an animation with a `nil` key (`[layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil]`), `animationKeys` returns `nil`.

Comment: @Martin sorry I can't tell, back then when I gave the answer it worked. Maybe something changed since iOS 4.x?

Comment: @Martin it does not work, if you fired animation with nil key. animationKeys is not array of animations, but array of their keys.

Comment: Implemented with swift 3 iOS 10 and this works for me when checking if a custom animation is finished when popping a view controller from the stack. Just make sure to set animation with a  key, and not nil. `self?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: "fade_animation")`

Comment: I did: `let alreadyAnimated = imageView.layer.animationKeys()?.isEmpty ?? true`

Answer (score 32):

**iOS 9+ method**, works even when `layer.animationKeys` contains no keys:

```
let isInTheMiddleOfAnimation = UIView.inheritedAnimationDuration > 0
```

From the docs:

> This method only returns a non-zero value if called within a UIView
>   animation block.

Answer (score 25):

Animations are attached in fact to the underlying Core Animation `CALayer` class

So I think you can just check `myView.layer.animationKeys`

Comment: animationKeys is a method. So you must call [myView.layer animationKeys]

Comment: animationKeys is a message, like any property accessor is... dot or brackets, just a matter of *style*.

Comment: But animationKeys is *not* a property ! https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html (of course, it's not very important :) )

Comment: properties are just semantics, everything end up as messages :) it really doesn't matter and compiler/static analysis does not care. As said, just a matter of style, I even use stuff like `UIView.class` or `UIColor.redColor` ... mostly because one dot is more readable and faster to type than 2 brackets and a space to my taste.

Comment: Really ? But compiler does not like it. I didn't try the execution, but it produce a warning with de dotted syntax.

Comment: there are cases when using that *trick* is rejected by compiler, like I think mixing static and non static methods: `MySincletonClass.sharedInstance.instanceMethod`. But i just checked, and `myView.layer.animationKeys` doesn't raise any warning / errors for me...

Comment: Works for me - i just check to make sure its nil and if so i animate.

Comment: IMHO code readability is more important than whether it compiles or not

Answer (score 12):

There are a lot of out-of-date answers here. I just needed to prevent a `UIView` animation being started if there was one running on the same view, so I created a category on `UIView`:-

```
extension UIView {

    var isAnimating: Bool {
        return (self.layer.animationKeys()?.count ?? 0) > 0
    }

}
```

This way I can just check any view's animation status like this:-

```
if !myView.isAnimating {
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
    ...
  }
} else {
  // already animating
}
```

This seems less fragile than keeping track of it with a state variable.

Comment: Sometimes you want to know exactly which property is animating (so as not to animate it again, particularly important with transforms). `func hasAnimation(_ key:String) -> Bool { guard let keys = layer.animationKeys() else { return false }  return keys.contains(key) }`

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure of the context of the question but I had was attempting to find out if a view was animating before starting a second animation to avoid skipping. However there is a UIView animation option `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` that will combine the animations if necessary to give a smooth appearance. Thereby eliminating my need to know if the view was animating.

Answer (score 5):

There is a hitch with the animationKeys trick.

Sometimes there could be a few animationKeys lingering after an animation is completed.

This means that a non-animating layer could return a set of animationKeys even if it isn't actually animating.

You can make sure that animationKeys are automatically removed by setting an animation's removedOnCompletion property to YES.

e.g.

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"aPath"];
animation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
```

If you do this for all the animations you apply to your layer, it will ensure that when the layer isn't animating there are no animationKeys present.

Answer (score 3):

Some of these didn't work for me. The reason for that is that these animations are asynchronous.

What I did is defined a property

```
@property BOOL viewIsAnimating;
```

And in my animation

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                 animations:^{
                     viewIsAnimating = YES;
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     if (finished) {
                         viewIsAnimating = NO;
                     }
                 }];
```

Comment: My UIButtons' animationKeys property was always returning nil (even when animating), so I also went this route to get the job done.

Comment: What happen if I use the option `.repeat` ?

Answer (score 1):

Ref to the question: [UIView center position during animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40096501/uiview-center-position-during-animation)

I compare the view's frame and layer.presentation()?.frame to check it is animating. If leftView is on the way to finish, the leftView.layer.presentation()?.frame does not equal to its frame:

```
if self.leftView.layer.presentation()?.frame == self.leftView.frame {
   // the animation finished
} else {
   // the animation on the way
}
```

But this method may not work if the view move to the end position during the animation. More condition check may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could query the presentation layer as suggested here [My presentation layer does not match my model layer even though I have no animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578646/my-presentation-layer-does-not-match-my-model-layer-even-though-i-have-no-animati)

Comment: According to the linked question, this approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the layer property of a UIView. CALayer has a property called animation keys, you can check its count if it is greater than 0.

```
if (view.layer.animationKeys.count) {

  // Animating

}else {

// No

}
```

In the Documentation:

```
-(nullable NSArray<NSString *> *)animationKeys;
```

> Returns an array containing the keys of all animations currently  *
>   attached to the receiver. The order of the array matches the order  *
>   in which animations will be applied.

Comment: You can make a category of UIView, and add this function for better reusability.