# How can I determine if an animation is currently playing in UIView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview, core-animation

I'd like to determine if a UITableView and other views are currently performing some type of animation with core animation.

In investigating this, I discovered the following Stack Overflow question & answer:
[how to tell if uiview is in middle of animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526476/how-to-tell-if-uiview-is-in-middle-of-animation)

I've verified that this technique of checking the animationKeys property works great for controls like UISlider, however when attempting to check for animationKeys during a UITableView animation, the NSArray count is always 0. I even went so far as to recursively check every view and layer in the view hierarchy for animationKeys, and all of them had a count of 0.

In looking into the addAnimation:forKey: selector of CALayer, I discovered that it's possible to add an animation with a nil key. This is probably the reason animationKeys has a count of 0. Due to this, I can't use the above linked technique.

The question: Is it even possible to reliably determine if an animation is currently playing? If so, what are some techniques for determining this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the delegate method`animationDidStart`:

> Delegate Methods
>
> animationDidStart: Called when the animation begins its active
>   duration.
>
> - (void)animationDidStart:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation Parameters theAnimation The CAAnimation instance that started animating.
>     Availability Available in iOS 2.0 and later. Declared In CAAnimation.h

Alternatively, you could query the`presentationLayer`and compare it to the model layer. For example:

```
CGPoint presentationPosition = myLayer.presentationLayer.position;
CGPoint modelPosition = myLayer.position;

BOOL animationInProgress = NO;

if (presentationPosition.x != modelPosition.x ||
    presentationPosition.y != modelPosition.y)
{
    animationInProgress = YES;
}
```