# UIPickerView, detect "rolling wheel" start and stop?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uipickerview

I just discovered that if I do the following:

1. Click the button that animates a `UIPickerView` into my view
2. Quickly start the wheel rolling towards, then past, the last item
3. Dismiss the view with a button

Then it has not yet selected the last item yet.

I tried this by simply outputting to the console whenever the `didSelectRow` method was fired, and it fires when the wheel stabilizes on the last item.

Can I detect that the wheel is still rolling, so that I can delay checking it for a selected value until it stabilizes?

If it matters, I'm programming in MonoTouch, but I can read Objective-C code well enough to reimplement it, if you have a code example that is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you can just check if the UIPickerView is in the middle of animating and wait for it to stop. This was answered here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526476/how-to-tell-if-uiview-is-in-middle-of-animation)

Comment: And how would you "check" the animation keys? Can you perhaps provide a more complete answer, one that would elaborate on such a methodology please. I came across your answer hoping to answer one question but I'm leaving with more questions now.

Comment: AnimationKeys doesn't seem to work in 2015.  DrainBoy's answer below worked for me, after I converted his code to Swift.

Answer (score 8):

As animation keys don't work, I wrote this simple function that works for detecting if a UIPickerView is currently moving.

```
-(bool) anySubViewScrolling:(UIView*)view
{
    if( [ view isKindOfClass:[ UIScrollView class ] ] )
    {
        UIScrollView* scroll_view = (UIScrollView*) view;
        if( scroll_view.dragging || scroll_view.decelerating )
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    for( UIView *sub_view in [ view subviews ] )
    {
        if( [ self anySubViewScrolling:sub_view ] )
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

It ends up returning true five levels deep.

Comment: Great, do you think that would be achievable with a listener pattern. I mean listening when the Picker starts dragging or decelerating and when it ends?

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4 (updated)** version with extension of @DrainBoy answers

```
extension UIView  {
 func isScrolling () -> Bool {

    if let scrollView = self as? UIScrollView {
        if  (scrollView.isDragging || scrollView.isDecelerating) {
            return true
        }
    }

    for subview in self.subviews {
        if ( subview.isScrolling() ) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `animationKeys` seems to not work anymore, I have another solution. If you check the subviews of `UIPickerView`, you'll see that there is a `UIPickerTableView` for each component.

This `UIPickerTableView` is indeed a subclass of `UITableView` and of course of `UIScrollView`.  Therefore, you can check its `contentOffset` value to detect a difference.

Besides, its `scrollViewDelegate` is nil by default, so I assume you can safely set an object of yours to detect `scrollViewWillBeginDragging`, `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`, etc.

By keeping a reference to each `UIPickerTableView`, you should be able to implement an efficient `isWheelRolling` method.

Comment: well, "scrollViewDelegate is nil by default" doesn't seem to be the case at least for UIDatePicker on iOS 13. Resetting it leads to disabling it's main purpose

Answer (score 3):

Expanded @iluvatar_GR answer

```
extension UIView { 
func isScrolling () -> Bool {

    if let scrollView = self as? UIScrollView {
        if (scrollView.isDragging || scrollView.isDecelerating) {
            return true
        }
    }

    for subview in self.subviews {
        if ( subview.isScrolling() ) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
func waitTillDoneScrolling (completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    var isMoving = true
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    while isMoving == true {
        isMoving = self.isScrolling()
    }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion()}

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Updating `isMoving` should probably be enclosed  in `DispatchQueue.main.sync { ... }`, otherwise there will be runtime warnings about accessing GUI components from a background thread.

Answer (score 1):

Expanded @iluvatar_GR, @Robert_at_Nextgensystems answer

Used Gesture, UIScrollView isDragging or isDecelerating.

```
// Call it every time when Guesture action.
@objc func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    // Changes the button name to scrolling at the start of scrolling.
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self._button.setTitle("Scrolling...", for: .normal)
       self._button.isEnabled = false
       self._button.backgroundColor = Utils.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "FF8FAE")
    }

    // Indication according to scrolling status
    _datePicker.waitTillDoneScrolling(completion: {
        print("completion")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self._button.setTitle("Completion", for: .normal)
           self._button.isEnabled = true
           self._button.backgroundColor = Utils.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "7CB0FF")
        }
    })
}
```

> **[SWIFT4] Share Example Source link!**
>
> [enter Sample Source link](https://github.com/FaithDeveloper/SampleRepository/tree/master/PickerView_Sample)

- Reference : [How to recognize swipe in all 4 directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215117/how-to-recognize-swipe-in-all-4-directions)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a SwipeGestureRecognizer on the picker.
I assume this is not a perfect solution at all.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _pickerSwipeGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [_pickerSwipeGestureRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    if([gestureRecognizer isEqual:_pickerSwipeGestureRecognizer]){
        NSLog(@"start");
    }
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSLog(@"end");
}
```