# How to restrict UIPickerView Component

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uipickerviewcontroller

How to restrict the `UIPickerView` component scrolling.

I have two components in `UIPickeView` one second component ends scroll allows user to touch the first component to change the value in it.

**How can I restrict the user to touch component one until and unless the second component scrolling complemented.**

Answer (score 0):

Using [this extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40565353/7084910), you can check UIPickerView is scrolling or not. Depend on scrolling, you can enable/disable interaction with UIPickerView.

```
extension UIView {

    func isScrolling () -> Bool {

        if let scrollView = self as? UIScrollView {
            if (scrollView.isDragging || scrollView.isDecelerating) {
                return true
            }
        }

        for subview in self.subviews {
            if subview.isScrolling() {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

UIPickerViewDelegate to detect scrolling or not.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if pickerView.isScrolling() {
        pickerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    } else {
        pickerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    //Use this for reduce lines
    //pickerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = !pickerView.isScrolling()

    return "Row \(row)"
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    pickerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

> The only problem is you can not touch current scrolling component, until component completed scrolling. HOPE, someone solve this also.