# How to detect is UI Picker View scrolling

Tags: scroll, view, uipickerview, uipicker

Im using AVSpeechSynthesizer,
playing text from UIPickerView
if I press play button firs I do picker.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
everything is ok
and in the end of play I do picker.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
but if I do scroll picker first and fast press play button sometimes I get this is error

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'NSMutableRLEArray objectAtIndex:effectiveRange:: Out of bounds'

my idea is check if picker scrolling - hide play button.

How to detect is UIPickerView scrolling?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40565353/7084910

Comment: its doesn't work, I checked and tried all what i find on stackoverflow

Comment: Check if picker is scrolling or not in titleForRow func. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51858233/7084910 also