# iOS find if a view is animating

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation

I'm trying to animate (fade in/out) a UILabel and I'm using the following code:

```
float newAlpha = 0.0;

//TODO:Check if the previous animation has finished

if(answer.alpha==0.0) {
    newAlpha = 1.0;
} else if(answer.alpha==1.0) {
    newAlpha = 0.0;
}
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    answer.alpha = newAlpha;
}];
```

Where the TODO comment is, I want to check if the previous animation has finished and if it hasn't, exit the method. Is there some way of doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to tell if uiview is in middle of animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526476/how-to-tell-if-uiview-is-in-middle-of-animation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE #1:**

you need a variable in your class:

```
BOOL _animationFinished;
```

and then you can use the following way for the animation:

```
float newAlpha = 0.0;

//TODO:Check if the previous animation has finished
if (_animationFinished == false) return;

if(answer.alpha==0.0) {
    newAlpha = 1.0;
} else if(answer.alpha==1.0) {
    newAlpha = 0.0;
}

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{ answer.alpha = newAlpha; _animationFinished = false; } completion:^(BOOL finished){ _animationFinished = true; }];
```

it must be work.

---

**ORIGINAL**

I'm always checking the subject of the animation in this case, like this:

```
float newAlpha = 0.0;

//TODO:Check if the previous animation has finished
if (answer.alpha > 0.f || answer.alpha < 1.f) return; // it is always good enough for me
// ...or with AND it will cause the same effect:
// if (answer.alpha > 0.f && answer.alpha < 1.f) return;

if(answer.alpha==0.0) {
    newAlpha = 1.0;
} else if(answer.alpha==1.0) {
    newAlpha = 0.0;
}
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    answer.alpha = newAlpha;
}];
```

Comment: Nice one, I didn't think of that solution. I'll give it a try and see if it works :)

Comment: you might use it, this way is perfectly good enough for me. I hope it helps. :)

Comment: No, this won't work the alpha of the component is set with 'answer.alpha = newAlpha' and the animation on the screen just catches up.

Comment: okay, there is an another solution, I'm working out it to you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using UIView then

```
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationfinished)];
-(void) animationfinished
{
      animationFinished = YES;
}
```

Comment: i still think its the best answer . because the animation block only support ios 4.0 and above

Answer (score 1):

Use [animateWithDuration:animations:completion:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a) method to do your "previous animation", and set a flag in the completion handler to indicate if it's finished or not. Then, check the same flag exactly where you have the TODO comment.

**Edit:** Example below

```
-(void) animation1 {
    // assume that alpha was 0 and we want the view to appear
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        answer.alpha = 1.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        fristAnimationFinished = finished;
    }];
}

-(void) animation2 {
    float newAlpha = 0.0;

    if (!firstAnimationFinished)
        return;

    if(answer.alpha==0.0) {
        newAlpha = 1.0;
    } else if(answer.alpha==1.0) {
        newAlpha = 0.0;
    }
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        answer.alpha = newAlpha;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Can you give me some sample code please, my 'previous animation' is just another alpha animation :)

Comment: At the line } completion:^{ I get an error "Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(void)' to a parameter of type 'void (^)(BOOL)" P.s. I like your helmet!

Comment: Now it's fine, this is why I placed the link to the method in my answer on the top.

Comment: What I'm completely unclear on is how you set the context of the view to be animated and where is it stored?

Comment: Everything happens in the _animateWithDuration:animations:_ method, [some properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW131) of the UIView are animatable so in this specific case the _answer.alpha_ is being animated.