# How to check if the code is run inside UIView's animation block

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function in my `UIView` subclass. This function adjust the layout of the view.

For example

```
func addItemAtIndex(index: Int){
    // layout the view
    item[index].frame.size = view.frame.size
}
```

I can call `myView.addItem(5)` as normal.

Since this function adjust the view's layout, I can also call this function inside `UIView`'s animation block. And it will layout the view with animation.

Like this,

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3){
    myView.addItem(5)
}
```

---

However, I want to do the different behaviour when it's animated. Is it possible to check if the function get called inside `UIView`'s animation block ?

Like this,

```
func addItemAtIndex(index: Int){
    if insideUIViewAnimationBlock{
        // layout with animation
    }else{
        // layout
    }
}
```

---

I'm not looking for `addItemAtIndex(index: Int, animated: Bool)` approach.

Comment: You subclassed ít, so you can add a method like `addItemWithAnimationAtIndex:` do the same thing as addItemAtIndex, plus some custom command, and call it in animation block?

Comment: Yes, I can. but I'm looking for cleaner code, so that I can call only one function, regardless of being call inside or outside `UIView`'s animation block.

Comment: @RMenke. Yes, I agree. But I think about the ease of use.  So there will be only one function to remember.  And then use animation block, as we animate things in iOS.

Comment: I think you can't do that without passing an argument or use another function. Only one way I can think about is that UIView animation runs on main thread, so if you call your function on another thread, you can do some thread checks. But that's too complicated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to tell if uiview is in middle of animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526476/how-to-tell-if-uiview-is-in-middle-of-animation)

Answer (score 0):

`CALayer` associated with the `UIView` is disabled implicit animation by default. It will be reenable inside an animation block. You can know whether inside or outside animation block to use that.

```
print("Outside animation block: \(self.view.actionForLayer(self.view.layer, forKey: "position"))")

UIView.animateWithDuration(5) { () -> Void in
    print("Inside animation block: \(self.view.actionForLayer(self.view.layer, forKey: "position"))")
}
```

For more information:
https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/view-layer-synergy/